# Convert std::max to Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, pointers

I have the current line in C/C++ code:

```
double ma = *std::max_element(Dists[a], Dists[a] + size);
```

`Dists[a]` is a double integer array of size `size`

```
int Dists[size][size];
```

I'm looking for an equivalent function in Java that would perform the same operation.

I'm not sure how this C/C++ function is working because of the "Dists[a] + size" line.

Comment: `max_element` takes a beginning and ending iterator and iterates through that range. Pointers are random-access iterators, and arrays decay into pointers when passed into a function. `Dists[a] + size` is the address for the ending iterator and uses pointer arithmetic, so it's the end of the array, and thus the entire array is iterated through. It's the same as using `std::begin(Dists[a])` and `std::end(Dists[a])`, but that might be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using `Collections`, and not an actual array (which is recommended):

```
ArrayList<Integer> a; // initialized somewhere
...
Collections.max(a);
```

If you're using an actual 2-dimensional array, try:

```
int[][] c; // initialized somewhere
int i; // set somewhere
List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(c[i]));
Collections.max(b);
```

Elements are compared [using their `natural ordering`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29).

Comment: Please provide how `Element` class can be compared. Also, you may need [`java.util.Collections#max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry, was just using it as a placeholder. Thanks :)

Comment: I referred that using a particular class (like `Element`) would mean that: 1. Your class must implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods, or 2. Provide a `Comparator`, but you haven't done any of those.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I guess that is a divergence from the C++ case in the question, where only a strict weak ordering comparison is required.

Comment: What I don't understand is how a double array (matrix) can be passed in to the max function, and how to replace it with Java code.

Comment: ANd since Dists[][] is a double array, what is the meaning of Dists[a]+size??

Comment: @TedGress since Dists is a 2-dimensional array, it can be through of as an array where every element is itself another array. Hence, Dists[a]+size means "get the array at Dists[a] and then get the pointer to the end of that array".

Comment: @Tushar so would that mean Dists[a]+size is equivalent to Dists[a+1]? Since Dists has a size of size? Dists[size][size]?

Comment: @TedGress yes, it does. However, if a == size, then even though "technically" you're correct, it'll be undefined to try and access Dists[a+1].