# "Shortcut" to determine maximum element in Iterator<IntWritable> in reduce() method

Tags: java, hadoop, max, reduce

I have written the below `reduce()` method to determine the maximum recorded temperature for a given year. (`map()`'s output gives a list of temperatures recorded in a year.)

```
public void reduce(IntWritable year
        , Iterator<IntWritable> temps
        , OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output
        , Reporter reporter) 
        throws IOException {
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while(temps.hasNext()) {
        int next = temps.next().get();
        if(next > maxValue) {
            maxValue = next;
        }
    }

    output.collect(year, new IntWritable(maxValue));
}
```

I am curious to know if there's a "shortcut", such as a pre-defined method, to eliminate the while loop, and obtain the maximum value directly. I am looking for something similar to [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)'s [`std::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). I found this ([Convert std::max to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15536668/252576)) by searching here, but I couldn't figure out how to convert my `Iterator<IntWritable>` to `Collections`.

I am a beginner in Java, but proficient in C++, so I am trying to learn various techniques used in Java as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to convert an `Iterator` into `Collections`, unless you use another library such as [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). With the second one for example, you can convert it to a `List` and then call the `Collection.max` function.

```
List<IntWritable> list = IteratorUtils.toList(temps);
```

If you don't want to use external libraries, then there is no other option. You could reduce a little bit your code with a for each loop, although the result is not that different:

```
for(IntWritable intWritable : temps) {
    if(intWritable.get() > maxValue) {
        maxValue = intWritable;
    }
}
```